# Javascript: How to execute at the Server Side (back-end)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, server-side, serverside-javascript

Lets say I want to do the JS execution, like, processing Javascript Elements but on the Server rather than exposing the code(s) on the client JS file.

Something like, lets say:

1. From the browser's side, lets say i will get the JS native `window` Object.
2. Then i want to make all **Javascript processing works** (on that `window` Object) **in the backend** by passing it to backend via Ajax, or whatever. So as an very simple examples (to do on the Backend JS Server):

   - Parse the `window.location` and do some codings related to it.
   - Parse the `window.document` and do some codings related to it.
3. And then return back to browser with the respective outcomes and then so on ..

So that means, (based on this simple example), i want to perform the parsing and whatever coding works, related to `window.location` & `window.document` Objects, in the backend (another) server. Just by passing this `window` Object to it. (Then return the already processed result back to the browser) So the user wont see what i am doing with this `window` object.

** Above is just a simple example. In fact, i want to pass some more complicated JS Objects and process at the backend.

That obvious point here is, i do not want my main JS processing codes to be exposed to the users.

1. Is this "concept" even possible please?
2. *(If possible, what is the ideal approach to this?)* Especially **for the BACKEND, what should i be running and HOW**, please?

Thanks

Comment: JS is a frontend stuff. All described things you can do with any backend language (e.g. PHP).

Comment: The answer is in your tags: `node.js` & `jquery`.

Comment: You would need to run some kind of AJAX function to send the object to the server to be manipulated. Once the server-side processing is done, you'd need JS to run the changes on the client

Comment: @jasonscript, what the `backend` looks like, please? I mean "how"?

Comment: AJAX. Use javascript/JQuery to send back ID's of the items you want to change, then respond from the server with HTML, which you inject where appropriate using Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: Gentlemen, i have updated my question, to be more precise. Please kindly look into it again. Thank you.

Comment: In essence, the question is the same, and the answer to "Is this "concept" even possible please?" is still "no".

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible as you describe.

JavaScript can run on the server, if your server has an engine to run the scripts. Node.js, which you tagged, is a good example of that.

But still, server and client are separated. The server cannot directly modify elements that are loaded into the client. The server feeds pages or other pieces of information to the client, which can be processed by the client.

So you could make an AJAX request to the server to perform some logic. This logic can be executed by PHP as well as Node.js, but when it comes to modifying the DOM, there is not much difference.

Node.js can be helpful, though. It supports a DOM as well, and I think you can even use jQuery, so an advantage over PHP is that you can do DOM manipulation in a similar way as on the client. It saves you a language to learn, but the client/server processing is still separated. You can't send an element with all its data and attached events to the server. You can send serialized objects at most.

Comment: I actually have updated my question, to be more precise. Please kindly look into it again. Thank you.

Comment: I see the update. In essence, the question remains the same, and so does the answer: You cannot send complete objects over the line. You can only send data. So if you need to process something when you click a button, you will have to post some data, or do an AJAX request to send data, and you will get a page or a chunk of data back.

Comment: Sorry, but let me confirm again. So you mean.. i CAN NOT pass the Javascript Objects to the backend (to process)? Not even to Node.js? (Or, is `node.js` the solution?)

Comment: Indeed, you cannot pass JavaScript Object to the backend. You can send serialized objects (JSON), but that is not the actual object.

Comment: So that we can not do anything at all with the Client's js objects, at the backend? (Thats hurt to know. I though we can pass to node.js and parse there, before) :S

Comment: There might be specific work-arounds for you, but your current question is way too broad to get into that. Please ask a new question, and clearly describe what kind of processing you need, Maybe there is a good way around it using AJAX.

Answer (score -4):

Javascript is a client-side programming language and all code is interpreted at runtime by the browser on the client's machine. So the short answer is no.

For server-side code, use a server-side programming language such as PHP, ASP.NET or ColdFusion.

Comment: Server side JavaScript was introduced by Netscape in 1994. That's right, one year before it was introduced (as LiveScript) in a browser. Today, you can pick any of these [Server side JavaScript solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions).